# How to use d3plus.TextBox() module for SVG line wrapping and automatic font size scaling ( on a D3.js Hierarchy Tree)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, d3plus

I am trying to use textBox module of d3plus-text for SVG textbox line-wrapping and automatic font size-scaling. I am following the use instructions from here https://github.com/d3plus/d3plus-text#d3plus-text

I am using the fucntion like so (as reccomended in the github) after updating the root tree:

```
    new d3plus.TextBox()
      .data(d3.select("text#rectResize"))
      .fontSize(16)
      .width(200)
      .x(function(d, i) { return i * 250; })
      .render();
```

But I am running into problems with the following error message:

```
d3plus-text.v0.10.full.min.js:7 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this._data.reduce is not a function
at i.a (d3plus-text.v0.10.full.min.js:7)
at test6.html:86
```

I have searched high and low but still not been able to make this work. Any help on this would be appreciated.

PS: I know I can use MikeBostics Wrap functionality which you can see I have used in the code below with some edits and it works. But I still want to learn how to use d3plus.TextBox as it seems more elegant and provides additional functionality.

Shorter version of my script is below. You can fiddle with it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/oze6ck05/1/)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<!-- load the d3.js library --> 
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3plus.org/js/d3plus-text.v0.10.full.min.js"></script>

<style>
    .node circle {
      fill: #FFF;
      stroke: #009BE4;
      stroke-width: 2px;
    }
    .node text {
      font: 12px sans-serif;
    }
    .link {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #555;
      stroke-width: 2px;
      stroke-opacity: 0.3;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <script>
        const circleSize = 8
        
        // Set the dimensions and margins of the diagram
        var margin = {top: 20, right: 90, bottom: 30, left: 90},
            width = 900 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 900 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
            
        // declares a tree layout and assigns the size
        var treemap = d3.tree().size([height, width]);
        
        // load the external data
        var flatData = [
            {"name": "This is a very long name for the top level", "parent": null},
            {"name": "This is a very long name for Level 2A", "parent": "This is a very long name for the top level" },
            {"name": "This is a very long name for Level 2B", "parent": "This is a very long name for the top level" },
            {"name": "This is a very long name for Son of A", "parent": "This is a very long name for Level 2A" },
            {"name": "This is a very long name for Daughter of A", "parent": "This is a very long name for Level 2A" }
            ];
            
            
            // assign null correctly
            flatData.forEach(function(d) {
                if (d.parent == "null") { d.parent = null};
                }); 
                
            // convert the flat data into a hierarchy
            var treeData = d3.stratify()
                .id(function(d) { return d.name; })
                .parentId(function(d) { return d.parent; })
                (flatData);
            
            
            // assign the name to each node
            treeData.each(function(d) {
            d.name = d.data.name;
            }); 
            
            // append the svg object to the body of the page
            // appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
            // moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
            var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
                .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate("
                      + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

            var i = 0,
            duration = 500,
            root;
            
            // Assigns parent, children, height, depth
            root = d3.hierarchy(treeData, function(d) { return d.children; });
            root.x0 = height / 2;
            root.y0 = 0;

            // Collapse after the second level
            root.children.forEach(collapse);
            update(root);
            
            new d3plus.TextBox()
              .data(d3.select("text#rectResize"))
              .fontSize(16)
              .width(200)
              .x(function(d, i) { return i * 250; })
              .render();
            
            // wrap text - not elegant way to wrap text         
            function wrap2(text, width) {
              text.each(function() {
                var text = d3.select(this),
                  // words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(), In order to prevent cutting through non-breaking spaces, replaced by below
                  words = text.text().split(/[ \f\n\r\t\v]+/).reverse(),
                  word,
                  line = [],
                  lineNumber = 0,
                  lineHeight = 1.2, // ems
                  y = text.attr("y"),
                  x = text.attr("x"),
                  dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy")),
                  tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", x).attr("y", y).attr("dy", dy + "em");
                while (word = words.pop()) {
                  line.push(word);
                  tspan.text(line.join(" "));
                  if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
                    line.pop();
                    tspan.text(line.join(" "));
                    line = [word];
                    tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", x).attr("y", y).attr("dy", lineHeight + "em").text(word);
                  }
                }
                // find corresponding rect and reszie
                d3.select(this.parentNode.children[0]).attr('height', 19 * (lineNumber+1));
              });
            }


            // Collapse the node and all it's children
            function collapse(d) {
              if(d.children) {
                d._children = d.children
                d._children.forEach(collapse)
                d.children = null
              }
            }

            function update(source) {
              // Assigns the x and y position for the nodes
              var treeData = treemap(root);

              // Compute the new tree layout.
              var nodes = treeData.descendants(),
                  links = treeData.descendants().slice(1);

              // Normalize for fixed-depth.
              nodes.forEach(function(d){ d.y = d.depth * 180});

              // ****************** Nodes section ***************************

              // Update the nodes...
              var node = svg.selectAll('g.node')
                  .data(nodes, function(d) {return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

              // Enter any new modes at the parent's previous position.
              var nodeEnter = node.enter().append('g')
                  .attr('class', 'node')
                  .attr("transform", function(d) {
                    return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
                })
                .on('click', click);

              // Add Circle for the nodes
              nodeEnter.append('circle')
                  .attr('class', 'node')
                  .attr('r', 1e-6)
                  .style("fill", function(d) {
                      return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
                  });

              // Add labels for the nodes
              nodeEnter.append('text')
                  .attr("id", "rectResize")
                  .attr("dy", "0em")
                  /* .attr("x", d => d.children ? -15 : 15) */
                  // .attr("text-anchor", d => d.children ? "end" : "start")
                  .attr("x", function(d) {
                      return d.children || d._children ? -15 : 15;
                  })
                  .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
                      return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
                  })
                  .text(function(d) { return d.data.name; })
                  .style("fill-opacity", 1)
                  // .call(wrap, 150)
                  .clone(true).lower()
                  .attr("stroke", "white");
              
              // UPDATE
              var nodeUpdate = nodeEnter.merge(node);

              // Transition to the proper position for the node
              nodeUpdate.transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .attr("transform", function(d) { 
                    return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
                 });

              // Update the node attributes and style
              nodeUpdate.select('circle.node')
                .attr('r', circleSize)
                .style("fill", function(d) {
                    return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
                })
                .attr('cursor', 'pointer');


              // Remove any exiting nodes
              var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
                  .duration(duration)
                  .attr("transform", function(d) {
                      return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
                  })
                  .remove();

              // On exit reduce the node circles size to 0
              nodeExit.select('circle')
                .attr('r', 1e-6);

              // On exit reduce the opacity of text labels
              nodeExit.select('text')
                .style('fill-opacity', 1e-6);

              // ****************** links section ***************************

              // Update the links...
              var link = svg.selectAll('path.link')
                  .data(links, function(d) { return d.id; });
                  

              // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
              var linkEnter = link.enter().insert('path', "g")
                  .attr("class", "link")
                  .attr('d', function(d){
                    var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0}
                    return diagonal(o, o)
                  });

              // UPDATE
              var linkUpdate = linkEnter.merge(link);

              // Transition back to the parent element position
              linkUpdate.transition()
                  .duration(duration)
                  .attr('d', function(d){ return diagonal(d, d.parent) });

              // Remove any exiting links
              var linkExit = link.exit().transition()
                  .duration(duration)
                  .attr('d', function(d) {
                    var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y}
                    return diagonal(o, o)
                  })
                  .remove();

              // Store the old positions for transition.
              nodes.forEach(function(d){
                d.x0 = d.x;
                d.y0 = d.y;
              });

              // Creates a curved (diagonal) path from parent to the child nodes
              function diagonal(s, d) {

                path = `M ${s.y} ${s.x}
                        C ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${s.x},
                          ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${d.x},
                          ${d.y} ${d.x}`

                return path
              }

              // Toggle children on click.
              function click(d) {
                if (d.children) {
                    d._children = d.children;
                    d.children = null;
                  } else {
                    d.children = d._children;
                    d._children = null;
                  }
                update(d);
              }
            }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: anyone from @d3plus